# How can we search in another branch than master in a private github repository?

Tags: github, search

On github, when I try to search throught my source code on a private repository, it always show me results from master branch. Is there a way to get results from another branch ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have finally found how to do it !

Go in the `settings` of your github repository, and then change the default branch in which you want to search :

[image: default branch selection]

Now you can search in the source code from this branch !

Comment: This may have unintended side-effects: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch

Comment: I think this shouldn't consider a good response. This side effects are very dangerous.

Comment: Indeed, but this is unfortunately the only way to do it online with github. I hope a feature request already exists on this subject...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `zsh`, here's a one liner to do it:

```
$ zipgrep 'string' =(curl -sL https://github.com/org/repo/archive/branch.zip)
```